# Facebook user profile image + sdk 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

A bit puzzled with this...

I am using LoginButton class to login via facebook in my app.

I have registered a callback loginButton.registerCallback and I can get login successfully with it, this all is done in LoginActivity class of my app.

As shown below, in onSuccess method of callback, I call getFaceBookProfileDetails method, defined locally to call Graph API to fetch user details, viz name, profile picture etc, this too works well .

```
onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
getFaceBookProfileDetails(loginResult.getAccessToken());
startActivity(intentHomeActivity)
}
```

Now the issue is I want to pass this facebook data to my HomeActivity where I will display this on UI.

As the graph API call runs Async on non-UI thread, I am getting Null pointer when I try to fetch this data in HomeActivity.

Looked at many work-arounds for this with no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
facebookButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
facebookButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile",    
"email", "user_birthday"));
intentHomeActivity = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
facebookButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

getFaceBookProfileDetails(loginResult.getAccessToken());
startActivity(intentHomeActivity);
}


public void onCancel() {

}
@Override
public void onError(FacebookException e) {

}
});


private void getFaceBookProfileDetails(final AccessToken accessToken) {

GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
accessToken,
new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

@Override
public void onCompleted(
final JSONObject object,
GraphResponse response) {
try {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Name   
is --"+object.get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User ID  is 
--"+object.get("id"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
ProfilePictureView profilePictureView =  new  
ProfilePictureView(getApplicationContext());

intentHomeActivity.putExtra(Constants.FACEBOOK_USER_OBJECT, 
object.get("id").toString());

} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
});

request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this line from the `onSuccess()` method:

```
    startActivity(intentHomeActivity);
```

To the `onCompleted()` method. After:

```
intentHomeActivity.putExtra(Constants.FACEBOOK_USER_OBJECT, object.get("id").toString());
```

The onComplete() method would look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCompleted( final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
    try {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Name is --" + object.get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User ID  is --" + object.get("id"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ProfilePictureView profilePictureView =  new  ProfilePictureView(getApplicationContext());
        intentHomeActivity.putExtra(Constants.FACEBOOK_USER_OBJECT, object.get("id").toString());
        startActivity(intentHomeActivity);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```